# Failed to post data using this.http.post using Angular from client's side

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, express

I'm trying to push data to MySQL database using Angular on the client' side and express JS on the server's side. The server side's post function side already worked when I test it using Postman. The code looks like this:

```js
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.post('/newPush', function(req, res) {
  var data = JSON.stringify(req.body);
  var dt = JSON.parse(data);
  let sql = 'INSERT INTO results(question1, question2, question3, question4)values("' + dt.question1 + '", "' + dt.question2 + '", "' + dt.question3 + '", "' + dt.question4 + '")';
  let query = db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    console.log(result);

    res.send(JSON.stringify(req.body) + 'success');
  })
})
```

I already tried to post some data using postman and it works. The that I post using postman posted to MySQL database successfully. And then I tried to post data from the client side using Angular Typescript but looks like I'm doing it wrong. The data doesn't appear in my database at all. I haven't figured it out what makes it didn't work. Here is how the code looks like on the client side using Angular:

```js
//component.ts

newForm: FormGroup;

constructor(private http: Http, public builder: FormBuilder) {
  this.newForm = this.builder.group({
    question1: [null],
    question2: [null],
    question3: [null],
    question4: [null],
  });
}

pushNewResults() {
  console.log('1', this.newForm.controls.question1.value);
  console.log('2', this.newForm.controls.question2.value);
  console.log('3', this.newForm.controls.question3.value);
  console.log('4', this.newForm.controls.question4.value);

  return this.http.post(
    'http://localhost:8000/newPush', {
      question1: this.newForm.controls.question1.value,
      question2: this.newForm.controls.question2.value,
      question3: this.newForm.controls.question3.value,
      question4: this.newForm.controls.question4.value
    });
}
```

```html
<div *ngIf="isVerified" align="left" class="container">
  <form [formGroup]="newForm">
    <div *ngFor="let items of jsonData">
      <div *ngFor="let items2 of items.question">
        <label>{{items2.questionid}}. {{items2.questiondesc}}</label>
        <div *ngFor="let items3 of items2.alloptions; let idx=index">
          <div class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="question{{items2.questionid}}" [value]="items3.answer" formControlName="question{{items2.questionid}}"><b>{{items3.options}}</b>. {{items3.answer}}
          </div>
        </div><br>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div align="center">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" (click)="pushNewResults(newForm)">SUBMIT</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

The values of `question1`, `question2`, `question3`, and `question4` appeared using `console.log` when submit but didn't make it into MySQL database. Can anyone help me figure it out, please? please let me know of more snippets are needed.

Comment: you need to `subscribe()` after your `http.post()`

Comment: your code have security issue, you should not construct SQL queries on client side!

Comment: @Chiu he did not. That is his express code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by @CozyAzure from comment section, i just need to add `subscribe()` after my `http.post()`.